# search values using like clause on alias column

Tags: mysql, alias

I have table which contain comma separated string I want to perform like query on 'name' column  but 'name' is comma separated so it will not retrieve data easily so I am using replace to eliminate comma and than perform like query on alias column ,but It is not working.is there any way to perform like query on comma separated string

Table:

```
id        name

i         school,education
```

mysql query :

```
    SELECT id,name, lower((REPLACE(name, ',', ''))) as test FROM `list`
    where test like '%education%'
```

Comment: As long as you are using prepared statements commas should not be an issue. MySQL does not allow aliases in `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously *avoid* storing CSV data into single table columns as you are currently doing.  That being said, here is one possible workaround:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM list
WHERE CONCAT(',', LOWER(name), ',') LIKE '%,education,%';
```

The idea behind the above trick is to build a CSV `name` string looking something like:

```
,A,B,C,D,
```

That is, every single name value is always surrounded by comma boundaries on both sides.  Then, we only need to check that `,somename,` be present in this CSV string.

Comment: you are right, data should be normalized but this table created by someone and as of now I am working on this code

Comment: @user_1234 Fair enough, sometimes we are forced to cope with other people's bad design decisions.  Then check my answer for one possible workaround.

Comment: I don't want to use comma so I eleminated comma using replace

Comment: And that approach won't work at all, because you will be left with just a single string containing _all_ names, and you won't have any way at all to reliably search for individual matches.